# Tkinter stops updating entry when the window moving

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making a program that solves sudoku and printing out the solving process on the screen using Tkinter.
It perfectly runs...if I do not move the window.

Here's a code that I think similary works:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
num = Label(root, text='READY', width=40)
num.pack()
def do():
    for i in range(100000):
        num.config(text=str(i))
        num.update()
start = Button(root, text='START', command=do)
start.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

It prints 1 to 99999 if I press button 'START'.
But if I move the window, it stops printing until I stop moving it.

How can I keep this running while moving the window?

Comment: There's no way we can debug something like this without a [mcve]. Moving a window shouldn't affect things at all.

Comment: I'll bet the problem goes away if you use `after` instead of `update`, but I can't test that unless you show a [mcve].

Comment: Tkinter runs on a single thread. When you click to drag a `<Configure>` event is triggered. The function bound to that event will take precedence and your `do()` method will be blocked until the event ends.

Comment: @pstatix It means I have to make the function bound to `<Configure>` event run on another thread?

Comment: @차우정 No, it means that whenever you click and drag the screen will stop updating. Thats pretty normal for applications. The program is redrawing itself the whole time you're dragging.

Comment: @pstatix Then, is there no way to keep the program updating whenever I do?